# Is there a maximum limitation on the number of physical volumes allowed in a volume group?

Tags: rhel, lvm

Someone in my organisation has picked up support for a system previously looked after by the now-defunct vendor. Their support department insisted there is a limit of 16 physical volumes on their virtual appliance, but this doesn't appear to be an LVM limit. They are using standard REHL under the covers -- we have root access.

I am looking for an authoritative answer as to what, if any, the LVM limits are so I can be sure this limitation comes from the old support outfit rather than the technology stack.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if probability of failure for single disk in lvm is 1%, having 16 disks in an lvm increases that probability of lvm failure to 16%, so testing the limits is not a good idea

Comment: This is a really interesting point in our case. We have a virtual appliance, so the underlying 16 "physical disks" are actually across 240+ real physical disks. Does that logic still apply?

Comment: I guess you're using a 16x16 grid, so if you're not doing replication, then a single disk failure in a row kills the whole lvm row, and if the column is also based on lvm, the column is killed too, killing the whole grid, so in that case probability of failure is multiplied

Comment: it's a ZFS system underneath: 24 RAID-Z3 groups with 10 disks each and one RAID-Z3 group with a different number (can't remember, maybe 8 -- legacy thing). All the "disks" on the virtual appliance are VHDs on a zvol, on a dataset that's on a pool that has 25 vdevs - as above. Not sure how I'd even start doing the failure probability calculations!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The maximum number of physical volumes depends on how the volume group is configured. `man vgcreate` states:

> -p|--maxphysicalvolumes Number
>                 Sets the maximum number of PVs that can belong to the VG.  The value 0 removes any limitation.  For large numbers of PVs,
>   also see options --pvmetadatacopies, and
>                 --vgmetadatacopies for improving performance.

You can check the current max physical volumes setting using `vgdisplay`; It's labeled **Max PV**.